# Wifi problems with TP-Link WN822N (Ubuntu 13.10)

Tags: wireless, 13.10

I am having a bit of trouble with my wifi on Ubuntu 13.10. I've never used Ubuntu or Linux before. I've just installed it on my new pc and I'm using a TP-Link WN822N USB Wireless Network adapter to run my internet. 
The problem is that my internet keeps going on hold... That is, the connection is there and seemingly working, however after about 5 minutes or so it will simply stop doing anything (without actually dropping out). I just disconnect, reconnect and then it works again for another 5 minutes, rinse and repeat.

Does anybody have any ideas about how I can fix this?

```
>>    cat /etc/lsb-release 

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=saucy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.10"

>>    lsusb 

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

>>    lspci -k -nn | grep -A 3 -i net 

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77-I Motherboard [1043:8505]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
03:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller [1b21:1042]

>>    sudo lshw -C network 

  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 09
       serial: bc:ee:7b:5c:b8:11
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168f-1_0.0.5 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:86 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d0004000-d0004fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 10:fe:ed:17:55:9a
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=3.11.0-15-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.11 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

>>    lsmod 

Module                  Size  Used by
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
rfcomm                 69130  0 
bnep                   19704  2 
bluetooth             372041  10 bnep,rfcomm
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     41117  1 
arc4                   12608  2 
kvm_amd                59987  0 
kvm                   431720  1 kvm_amd
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13259  0 
aesni_intel            55624  2 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
rtl8192cu              67723  0 
rtl_usb                18448  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                63229  2 rtl_usb,rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        48877  1 rtl8192cu
mac80211              597268  3 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              480503  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
joydev                 17377  0 
eeepc_wmi              13151  0 
asus_wmi               24191  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  1 asus_wmi
video                  19318  1 asus_wmi
mxm_wmi                13021  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    55704  1 
snd_hda_intel          48171  10 
snd_hda_codec         188738  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
microcode              23576  0 
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102033  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
radeon               1402995  3 
edac_core              62342  0 
edac_mce_amd           22617  0 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
psmouse                97655  0 
fam15h_power           13119  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              13413  0 
k10temp                13126  0 
sp5100_tco             13979  0 
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
i2c_piix4              22106  0 
snd_rawmidi            30095  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
ttm                    84169  1 radeon
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29433  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
drm_kms_helper         52710  1 radeon
drm                   297056  5 ttm,drm_kms_helper,radeon
snd                    69141  31 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
soundcore              12680  1 snd
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 radeon
mac_hid                13205  0 
wmi                    19070  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42299  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_logitech_dj        18581  0 
usbhid                 53014  0 
hid                   105858  4 usbhid,hid_logitech_dj
ahci                   25819  3 
r8169                  67581  0 
libahci                31928  1 ahci
mii                    13934  1 r8169
[/code]
[code]

>>    iwconfig 

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"SKY12795"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 7C:4C:A5:7E:F0:ED   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=63/70  Signal level=-47 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:13   Missed beacon:0


>>    ifconfig -a 

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:ee:7b:5c:b8:11  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3428 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3428 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:308618 (308.6 KB)  TX bytes:308618 (308.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:fe:ed:17:55:9a  
          inet addr:192.168.0.11  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::12fe:edff:fe17:559a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:405566 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:239178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:548420692 (548.4 MB)  TX bytes:25583338 (25.5 MB)


>>    sudo iwlist scan 

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 7C:4C:A5:7E:F0:ED
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"SKY12795"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000006169da3baa
                    Extra: Last beacon: 168ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0008534B593132373935
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEC181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD800050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010B4507EEEC180E6FEE48483EAC36299C31021000842726F6164636F6D1023000842726F6164636F6D1024000631323334353610420004313233341054000800060050F20400011011000A42726F6164636F6D415010080002200C103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180206F02C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 02 - Address: 02:AC:54:EA:B0:92
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=10 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"BTWiFi"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000009594434036
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1692ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0006425457694669
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC011BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601001100000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101890003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
          Cell 03 - Address: 12:AC:54:EA:B0:92
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=63/70  Signal level=-47 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"BTWiFi-with-FON"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000959442c180
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1724ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000F4254576946692D776974682D464F4E
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050401030000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC011BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601001100000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101890003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 04 - Address: 00:AC:54:EA:B0:92
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=10 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"BTHub3-H4C3"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000009594424f37
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1700ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000B4254487562332D48344333
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B960C121824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32043048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC011BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601001100000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101890003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: Unknown: DDA70050F204104A000110104400010210570001001041000100103B00010310470010565AA94967C14C0EAA8FF349E6F5931110210002425410230017486F6D652048756220332E30204D756C7469204D6F646510240010425420486F6D652048756220332E3041104200122B3035383732302B313231393031333633311054000800060050F204000110110010425420486F6D652048756220332E3041100800020084103C000101
          Cell 05 - Address: 7C:4C:A5:2F:E0:11
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"SKY37AC9"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000005228d7ac7
                    Extra: Last beacon: 76ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0008534B593337414339
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEC181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606080000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD800050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700105798F8620325A8E730D0D990FC0834191021000842726F6164636F6D1023000842726F6164636F6D1024000631323334353610420004313233341054000800060050F20400011011000A42726F6164636F6D415010080002200C103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180200F02C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 06 - Address: 7C:03:4C:A7:D8:A8
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"SKY7D8A7"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000576e3dae0d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 72ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0008534B593744384137
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AFC181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606001500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD760050F204104A0001101044000102103B00010310470010EA05F98F66DAAA215D3A6F92626310B81021000842726F6164636F6D1023000842726F6164636F6D1024000631323334353610420004313233341054000800060050F20400011011000A42726F6164636F6D4150100800020084103C000101
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180204F02C0000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 07 - Address: 30:46:9A:7C:1E:14
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=10 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"virginmedia8250852"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000933dba269e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 28ms ago


>>    uname -r -m 

3.11.0-15-generic x86_64

>>    cat /etc/network/interfaces 

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

>>    nm-tool 


NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [SKY12795] ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192cu
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        10:FE:ED:17:55:9A

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           72 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    SKY37AC9:        Infra, 7C:4C:A5:2F:E0:11, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 94 WPA2
    BTWiFi:          Infra, 02:AC:54:EA:B0:92, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 10
    BTWiFi-with-FON: Infra, 12:AC:54:EA:B0:92, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 10
    virginmedia8250852: Infra, 30:46:9A:7C:1E:14, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 10 WPA WPA2
    TALKTALK-6A9669: Infra, 00:26:B6:6A:96:69, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA WPA2
    BTBusinessHub-170_EXT: Infra, 9C:D3:6D:A7:71:9E, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA WPA2
    SKY7D8A7:        Infra, 7C:03:4C:A7:D8:A8, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 82 WPA WPA2
    TALKTALK-C2F5B0: Infra, 90:94:E4:C2:F5:B0, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 10 WPA WPA2
    Fowza-at-home-Wireless: Infra, 00:26:F2:50:FC:18, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 62 WPA WPA2
    *SKY12795:       Infra, 7C:4C:A5:7E:F0:ED, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 72 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.11
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        BC:EE:7B:5C:B8:11

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off



>>    sudo rfkill list 

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: I can't help you, but TP-LINK TL-WN/722N works really fine :/ Does your USB adapter works with a Live-CD session ?

Comment: Hello :) Yeah I read that that one works well... actually I bought all my pc parts before I knew I was going to use Linux so I'm playing 'fix it' a bit with a bunch of my stuff... Umm in terms of a CD, it did come with a mini-disk, however I have no CD drive!

Comment: No, I mean : when your run a live session of Ubuntu (like if you wanted to install Ubuntu, using live-cd, live-usb), does Wifi works fine ?

Comment: Oh, I see! Yes, it worked fine the whole time. However I booted Ubuntu 13.04 and then updated right away. It's only after the update that I've had the issue.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue on 13.10. very annoying! my tenda w22u v2 is working fine

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The RTL driver is not so good, so thankfully, some pretty smart people found a good solution; I've just installed it and am connecting solidly with no lost or drop outs. Follow these links, read carefully and apply: "Seek first to understand." (- Suzanne Brown). Smiles await you.

https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes/blob/master/README.md   (easiest to follow but read the others to help you understand what you are doing.)

http://tuxstack.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/install-drivers-for-wifi-usb-adapters-trendnet-tew-624ub-tp-link-wn821n-asus-edimax-etc-on-linux/     (the nuts & bolts)

Comment: The pvaret solution on Github fixed my problem in Xubuntu 14.10 by installing an improved version of Realtek's own 8192CU driver for USB WiFi devices, since RealTek hasn't updated the driver since 2012.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer**, but will help troubleshoot with important informations, and the message is too long to be placed in comments. Sorry 'bout that.

---

**AUTOMATIC VERSION :** (uses a script)

To help troubleshooting your Wireless connexion, you can add some important informations by running a simple script.

1. Download this : [wificheck.sh](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/_export/code/wificheck?codeblock=0)
2. Put the file on your HOME folder (`~/` or `/home/username`)
3. Open a terminal (CTRL-ALT-T)
4. Run the script (question is in french, but answer 'y' for yes) :

   ```
   sudo bash wificheck.sh && sudo chmod 777 wificheck.log
   ```
5. Open the newly created file *wificheck.log* and post the content on Askubuntu.com or Ubuntuforums.org

It contains all informations about your hardware/software wifi-related.

---

**MANUAL VERSION :** (uses commandlines, copy-paste and text-editor)

Now, this will do the same thing as the script (= give information helpfull for troubleshooting wireless connexion), but whitout a script. You will do everything manually with commandlines. Paste the return of each command in a text-file or the thread you opened.

`cat /etc/lsb-release`

`lsusb`

`lspci -k -nn | grep -A 3 -i net`

`sudo lshw -C network`

`lsmod`

`iwconfig`

`ifconfig -a`

`sudo iwlist scan`

`uname -r -m`

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`

`nm-tool`

`sudo rfkill list`

Comment: Right okay... I have done the first part, I'll post it as an edit of my question. Then I should do this second part (individual command lines) as well?

Comment: No, the second part is **exactly** the same as the script in 1st part, except that you don't run a script, you do everything with your bare hands.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I'm new to this! Okay, I'll post my result now as an edit.

Comment: I may have been unclear. I edited my answer to clarify^^

Comment: No no, I understand. I'm just being a noob :)