# Problem on Xubuntu 14.04 with TP-Link WN822Nv4

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, xubuntu

I've recently obtained the TP-Link WN822Nv4 (EU) adapter because my onboard adapter doesn't seem to work very well (low signal strength, my phone gets 10x the speeds), however I can't for the life of me figure out how to make it work. I've tried searching the site for similar things (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/820886/587662) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/401045/587662), the second one reported an error of some kind), but none of them seem to work. My laptop is a HP Pavilion G6-2002SM if it matters.

Output of `lsusb` ( Device 004 is the adapter I think):

```
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 04f2:b2f4 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 2357:0108  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Version:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux bloop 3.19.0-42-generic #48~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 18 10:24:49 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lshw -C network`:

```
*-network               
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:c3500000-c3503fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 05
   serial: 80:c1:6e:60:1c:38
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:27 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3404000-c3404fff memory:c3400000-c3403fff
 *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: c0:18:85:1b:0d:21
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.19.0-42-generic firmware=610.812 ip=10.40.101.111 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

`dkms status`:

```
8192cu, 1.10, 3.19.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8192eu, 4.3.1.1.11320.20140505~trusty1: added
```

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

I'm not too familiar with troubleshooting on Linux so I can't figure out how to solve the problem. Any advice?

Comment: You installed wrong drivers.

Comment: @Pilot6 Isn't rtl8192eu correct?

Comment: I am looking into it. But it is unclear which one is installed. My source does not have that ID. And the 3.19 kernel is not supported. I would suggest to upgrade the kernel to 4.4 first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice the kernel version, to update to 4.4 you can

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

We need to get rid of one of the dkms installs as I am not sure Pilot6 updated his PPA for Trusty

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8192eu/4.3.1.1.11320.20140505~trusty1 --all
```

```
sudo dkms remove 8192cu/1.10 --all
```

Reboot

Then we can install git and build-essential

`sudo apt-get install git build-essential`

Then we can clone Mange's github code

`git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git`

Then use dkms to add it
`sudo dkms add ./rtl8192eu-linux-driver`

Then install

`sudo dkms install -m rtl8192eu -v 1.0`

Reboot

Mange's code will support your device because of a commit made 6 months ago

```
+    /===TPLINK ID===========/
 +  {USB_DEVICE(0x2357, 0x0107),.driver_info = RTL8192E}, /* TP-Link - Cameo /
 +  {USB_DEVICE(0x2357, 0x0108),.driver_info = RTL8192E}, / TP-Link - Cameo /
 +  {USB_DEVICE(0x2357, 0x0109),.driver_info = RTL8192E}, / TP-Link - Cameo */
  #endif
```

Comment: Also removing `8192cu` does make sense.

Comment: I did not update for `trusty`, but the deb can be downloaded from the xenial. Also upgrading kernel to 4.4 is recommended.

Comment: This worked even without the kernel update, though the speeds are a bit lower than when using Win8. Not sure if this is a consequence of not updating, but the DL/UL are nonetheless way faster than on the default adapter, thanks!

Comment: I do recommend changing to a supported kernel for Ubuntu 14.04 so that you get kernel security updates.  If `lshw -c video` shows only Intel video the kernel update should be painless.  The dkms should built the wireless module in 4.4 without issue as that is the kernel I tested it with